# SSL connection with just_a_name.cer and just_a_name.p7b to import into cacerts in Java failure

Tags: java, ssl, webserver, ssl-certificate, wildfly-10

I'm not being able to import just_a_name.pb7 to "cacerts" keystore in order to enable SSL to a wildfly webserver. Most of the error when trying to import to keystore is this

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

when I execute the next command:

```
keytool -import -alias just_a_name_p7b_alias -keystore  cacerts -file /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/just_a_name.p7b
```

just_a_name.cer is already imported into "cacerts" with this command

```
keytool -import -alias just_a_name_alias -keystore  cacerts -file /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/just_a_name.cer
```

Anyone have an idea what can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to import `just_a_name.p7b` anyway?

Comment: @JamesKPolk what would be the right way to do it? I have try to start the wildfly webserver just with just_a_name.cer file in server.log shows that "cacerts" file does not contain any valid key so I decided to try to import "just_a_name.p7b" file into "cacerts" keystore.

Comment: I can't tell if your problem is on the server or the client, or even what the problem is. Did you get `just_a_name.p7b` from a certificate authority? Providing these kinds of details can really help someone answer your question.